# psql errors on restore database

Tags: postgresql, psql

Please read a litle story first. So I have a front end application that run on a SUSE Linux Enterprise 9 PC and PostgreSQL 7.4.2 database server.
Now I installed on a Windows 8.1 PC postgresql-9.5.1 from get.enterprisedb.com.
When I want to restore the backup from SUSE (that was made from a menu item of the front end application) with the command:

psql -U admin -d MyDataBase -f BackupDatabase

I receive a lot of errors like:

```
    ^
```

psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27100: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Scara"
LINE 1: Scara: A;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27101: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 20;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27102: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Ü8"
LINE 1: Ü?Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27103: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Bulevardul"
LINE 1: Bulevardul: AUREL VLAICU;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27104: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27105: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: C6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27106: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 48;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27107: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WLocalitate"
LINE 1: WLocalitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27108: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: CAIUTI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27109: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 27;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27110: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27111: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: CRINULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27112: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 19;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27113: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27114: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: DRAGOSLAVELE;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27115: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 1B;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27116: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: 1A;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27117: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 9;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27118: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""Localitate"
LINE 1: "Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27119: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: OBORULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27120: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 54;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27121: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: L2;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27122: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Scara"
LINE 1: Scara: B;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27123: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 34;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27124: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "┼Localitate"
LINE 1: ┼Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27125: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: PRELUNGIREA LILIACULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27126: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27127: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: G8;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27128: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 50;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27129: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27130: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: STEFAN CEL MARE;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27131: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 57;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27132: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: M17;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27133: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 24;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27134: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "eme"
LINE 1: eme.Localitate: Mereni;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ńwĆ"
LINE 1: ńwĆ
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "˘ţŤ"
LINE 1: ˘ţŤ;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "˘ţŤ"
LINE 1: ˘ţŤ;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "o"
LINE 1: o↕?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "uLp"
LINE 1: uLp;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27147: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "uLp"
LINE 1: uLp;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "∟"
LINE 1: ∟♀×#=∟♀>Ý`
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Öę?"
LINE 1: Öę?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Öę?"
LINE 1: Öę?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "o"
LINE 1: o↕?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "o"
LINE 1: o↕?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "o"
LINE 1: o↕?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "o"
LINE 1: o↕?;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "∟"
LINE 1: ∟ů⌂?śů⌂?śů⌂?ś♀]?<×Ł<Öę?<|Í<ŹÂuD"
LINE 1: |>D;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|>D"
LINE 1: |>D;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "|>D"
LINE 1: |>D;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 1: >Ă.;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 1: >Ă.;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 1: >Ă.;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27153: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 1: >Ă.;
        ^
☼▲◄♀☻". available for "▼→♥gupa↕; agem↕↕g▬N↨X ☼@☺☻; ┌g☺4g☺(☻►=♦?☻
Try \h with no arguments to see available help.

psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27171: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "∟"
LINE 1: .resources.resource.9.typede5zĆ♀4VĎm_1181127081303.zipbp"]...
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27171: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: )R6↔ ^H§"0Ű☺k‼"d§}↔=$ç♂▬order b'y ´ nt♀▲Á☺ůlocal"ć☻@'m♂"Me...
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27174: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "l"
LINE 1: l◄!L'♠Z su‼ŕraI_c◄1⌂ nl/ç &tšl‼Sl§=↔=n☼§☺E☼U♥m☺Ř nm☻Km☼...
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27175: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27176: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Bulevardul"
LINE 1: Bulevardul: 1 DECEMBRIE 1918;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27177: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27178: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: L56;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27179: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Scara"
LINE 1: Scara: B;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27180: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 25;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27181: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27182: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Bulevardul"
LINE 1: Bulevardul: 1 MAI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27183: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 3;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27184: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: H10;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27185: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Scara"
LINE 1: Scara: A;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27186: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 20;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27187: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27188: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Bulevardul"
LINE 1: Bulevardul: AUREL VLAICU;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27189: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27190: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: C6;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27191: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 48;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27192: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WLocalitate"
LINE 1: WLocalitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27193: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: CAIUTI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27194: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 27;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27195: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27196: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: CRINULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27197: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 19;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27198: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Localitate"
LINE 1: Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27199: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: DRAGOSLAVELE;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27200: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 1B;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27201: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: 1A;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27202: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 9;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27203: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""Localitate"
LINE 1: "Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27204: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: OBORULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27205: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 54;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27206: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Blocul"
LINE 1: Blocul: L2;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27207: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Scara"
LINE 1: Scara: B;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27208: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Apartamentul"
LINE 1: Apartamentul: 34;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27209: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "┼Localitate"
LINE 1: ┼Localitate: Constanta;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27210: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Strada"
LINE 1: Strada: PRELUNGIREA LILIACULUI;
        ^
psql:d:/Ael_DB.tar:27211: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NumÄ?r"
LINE 1: NumÄ?r arterÄ?: 6;
        ^

I did not let the command to finish since the database has 6 GB and would last too long.

The question is where I am wrong or missing something ?

Comment: `psql` must be fed with an SQL script. the fact that your file is named `Ael_DB.tar` is suspicious. Is it a tar file? Look at the beginning of that file to figure out what it is exactly. Use `head -n 100` if you have a Unix shell to display the first 100 lines.

Comment: I give it the name. The initial backup was a .tgz file that I unzipped with 7z on the Windows 8.1 machine